# Is there a way to catch all exceptions and display them to user in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, testing

I'm writing an iPhone/iPad app and I'm undergoing beta testing by other employees of my company (many of whom are out of the country). My question is, is there anyway to catch all exceptions or errors for the program and display them to the user.

What I'm thinking is, someway to wrap the main method with a try catch and then, if there is any error (such as indexOutOfBounds) it would display a UIAlert to the user stating what the error is and where it occurred.  That way it would be easier for my testers to tell me exactly what error they are experiencing.

If this is not possible, is there any good way for me to tell what errors testers of my program are having other than just having them tell me things such as "I pressed this button and the app crashed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into something like the [TestFlight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) or [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/).

Answer (score 1):

you can also make your testers test the application in debug run mode while connecting to xcode debugger (on device debug) there you will find most of the issues with their reasons. Other way would be the use of instruments app which is bundled with XCode and iOS SDK. it is a great way to debug the app and at last, you can use the third party libraries for reporting logs like a few suggested by @Amy.

Comment: The problem is, some of my testers are not programmers (they are sales people) and they would freak out if I told them to open Xcode...lol :)